# Thread safe collection or concurency for same keys in each Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have `List<List<File>>` which I divide for chunks. For each chunk I run `n` Threads. Each Thread build `TreeMap<String, List<String>>`. I wanted to connect all `TreeMap<String, List<String>>`'s to single (but they can contain same key - so some comparations needs to be done) or I would to run use some thread-safe `collection` or `concurent` but I don't know which? (it needs to be possible to sort) and the `key` could be the same in each Thread but their `values` needs to be connected.

```
List<File> filesAndFoldersList = Arrays.asList(filesAndFoldersArray);

        List<List<File>> filesArrays = divideArrayIntoChunks(filesAndFoldersList, 100);
        

        for (int i = 0; i < filesArrays.size(); i++) {

            List<File> filesList = filesArrays.get(i);

            BuildNamesAndFileNamesMap buildNamesAndFileNamesMap = new BuildNamesAndFileNamesMap(... , i);

            Thread thread = new Thread(buildNamesAndFileNamesMap, "Thread " + i);
            thread.start();

            if (buildNamesAndFileNamesMap.hasFinished()) {

                namesAndFileNamesPartMap = buildNamesAndFileNamesMap.getNamesAndFileNamesMap();
                ... // join to main TreeMap or?
            }
            
        }
```

This is **BuildNamesAndFileNamesMap.class**:

```
private static class BuildNamesAndFileNamesMap implements Runnable {

        ....
        private final TreeMap<String, List<String>> namesAndFileNamesMap;
        private int threadNumber;

        private boolean hasFinished = false;

        public BuildNamesAndFileNameMap(..., int threadNumber) {

            ...
        }

        public TreeMap<String, List<String>> getNamesAndFileNamesMap() {
            return namesAndFileNamesMap;
        }

        public boolean hasFinished() {
            return hasFinished;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            ...

            namesAndFileNamesMap.put(...);
            hasFinished = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that what you posted is pseudocode (otherwise, how does the synchronous `buildNamesAndFileNamesMap.hasFinished()` work)?

The simplest would be to use a synchronization mechanism like `CountDownLatch` and `await()` termination of all threads on the main thread. You can then merge all the results into a synchronous `Map` using `Map.merge`, for example, thus eliminating the need for a concurrent collection (for a cleaner design, you might want to look into [`CompletableFuture.allOf(...)`](https://medium.com/@kalpads/fantastic-completablefuture-allof-and-how-to-handle-errors-27e8a97144a0))

If you want more parallelism than that (i.e. collecting intermediate results performed by the child threads themselves, rather than a post-processing step), you would need to make the `BuildNamesAndFileNameMap` instances share a concurrent collection (since it sounds you will need `Map.merge` for merging results from different threads, a `ConcurrentHashMap` will be most appropriate, otherwise if no merging is needed then a `ConcurrentSkipListMap` would be enough).